# Form Freezing after Calculations

Tags: vba, excel

I'm running the below code from a Form that has a loading bar, it works perfectly... when there roughly 6000 rows, but when it gets to around the 8000th row mark, the Form freezes. It does eventually complete the process of every row, but it doesn't update my progress bar that I implemented.

I've tried changing the `Mod` value from a few different numbers ranging from `5 to 500` and it still freezes around the 8000th row.

```
With ActiveSheet
      For i = 2 To LR
         Set newASN = New cASN

         If (i Mod 500) = 0 Then
            frmMainMenu.frameBar.Width = (i / LR) * 100
            frmMainMenu.labelPctComplete.Caption = Int((i / LR) * 100) & "%"
            frmMainMenu.labelTotalASNnum.Caption = i
            frmMainMenu.Repaint
         End If

         For j = 1 To LC
            AddData newASN, j, .Cells(i, j).value
         Next j
         ASN_COL.Add newASN
      Next i
         frmMainMenu.frameBar.Width = 100
         frmMainMenu.labelPctComplete.Caption = "100%"
         frmMainMenu.labelTotalASNnum.Caption = i - 1
   End With
```

**Does anyone know how to prevent the freezing of this Form?**

Please let me know if there's anything else I need to add or clarify here... I think I may have covered all the ground that I'm having issues with.

Comment: Are you switching off the usual suspects e.g. ScreenUpdating.......?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, I have turned those off in the call of `AddData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out... I added in a call to `DoEvents` and that seemed to stop the screen from freezing up! :)

```
With ActiveSheet
      For i = 2 To LR
         Set newASN = New cASN

         If (i Mod 500) = 0 Then
            frmMainMenu.frameBar.Width = (i / LR) * 100
            frmMainMenu.labelPctComplete.Caption = Int((i / LR) * 100) & "%"
            frmMainMenu.labelTotalASNnum.Caption = i
            frmMainMenu.Repaint
            DoEvents    'Added the line here
         End If

         For j = 1 To LC
            AddData newASN, j, .Cells(i, j).value
         Next j
         ASN_COL.Add newASN
      Next i
         frmMainMenu.frameBar.Width = 100
         frmMainMenu.labelPctComplete.Caption = "100%"
         frmMainMenu.labelTotalASNnum.Caption = i - 1
   End With
```

Comment: Doing `DoEvents` on *every* iteration of the For loop will slow things down quite a bit.  Given Excel doesn't "freeze" until you've processed 6000 or so rows, I'd suggest putting the `DoEvents` inside your `If (i ... ` block

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thank, I changed the code to only be in the `DoEvents` in the progress bar and I noticed a roughly 30% increase in speed. Great suggestion thank you